# Prove that $\int_0^{\pi} \sin^2 x\, dx = 2 \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^2 x\, dx$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

It can be observed that
$$\sin^2 \left( x + \frac{\pi}{2} \right) = \cos^2 (x)$$
Being the squared cosine an even function, the squared sine will be symmetrical as well, but with respect to $x = \pi / 2$.

Are there any other approaches for this proof? Is there anything else that can be observed, hopefully about the $\sin^2 x$ function itself, without considering the space-shift $x + \pi / 2$ and the cosine?

Comment: I would say your approach is the smart one.

Comment: This is a result of the popular integral formula $$\int_{0}^{2a}f(x)\,dx=2\int_{0}^{a}f(x)\,dx$$ if $f(2a-x)=f(x)$. The integral is $0$ if $f(2a-x)=-f(x)$. For your question $a=\pi/2$ and $f(x) =\sin^{2} x$.

Comment: $$\sin^2x=\frac{1-\cos 2x}2$$

and 

$$\int \sin^2x\,dx=\frac x2-\frac14\sin 2x+C.$$

Hence

$$\int_0^{k\pi/2} \sin^2x\,dx=\frac{k\pi}4.$$

Answer (score 3):

The function $\sin^2(x)$ is periodic of period $\pi$, which implies that
$$\int_0^{\pi} \sin^2 x dx=\int_a^{a+\pi} \sin^2 x dx$$
for any real number $a$.
 Therefore, 
$$\int_0^{\pi} \sin^2 x dx =\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \sin^2 x dx=2 \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^2 x dx$$
where in the last step we used the fact that $\sin^2(x)$ is even.

Comment: Ha! +1 for the rapidity, I was going to post an IDENTICAL answer lol

Answer (score 2):

For *every* integrable function $f\colon[0,\pi]\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ such that$$(\forall x\in[0,\pi]):f(x)=f(\pi-x),$$the equality$$\int_0^\pi f(x)\,\mathrm dx=2\int_0^{\frac\pi2}f(x)\,\mathrm dx$$ holds, since$$\int_\frac\pi2^\pi f(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int_0^\frac\pi2f(\pi-x)\,\mathrm dx=\int_0^\frac\pi2 f(x)\,\mathrm dx.$$

Comment: (+1) I've deleted my less general hint. This seems most direct to me.